# How can I reverse a range of list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 test [0, 2] and [3, 4]

and my list is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

how can I reverse only in range from 0-2 and 3-4 to my list

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [3, 2, 1, 4, 5] -> [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]

this is my code. It only works in first time, and second time it not works! 
How can I fix it?

```
def solution(arr):
    test1 = [1, 3]
    test2 = [4, 5]
    totalTest = [test1, test2]
    print(arr)
    for x in totalTest:
        a = []
        for i in x:
            a.append(i-1)

        lenght = (a[1] - a[0] + 1)/2
        index = a[1] - a[0]
        # print(lenght)

        for i in range(a[0], lenght):    # i is the low index pointer
            arr[index], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[index]
            index -= 1

        print(arr)


arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
solution(arr)
```

The above code outputs the result:

[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]

Comment: This is a tiny program. You haven’t even told is what the problem is! I strongly recommend reading the following: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I mean, I'll change it twice in a list. That list will be exchanged for the first time, taking the list that was exchanged for the first time and exchanged for a second time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list slicing as follow:
keep in mind that the lower bound is inclusive, but the upper bound is not
so if you want to slice a list from index `0` to index `2` you would do `mylist[0:3]`

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mylist = mylist[0:3][::-1] + mylist[3:5][::-1]
# [3, 2, 1, 5, 4]
```

Comment: You don't need to use indexing twice, just do `mylist = mylist[2::-1] + mylist[4:2:-1]`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I prefer this way bc it's a little bit more readable

Answer (score 0):

You should break your list in two and reverse each part separately:

```py
  li = [1,2,3,4,5]
  print(li[0:3][::-1] + li[3:5][::-1])
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a more general function to do this:

```
def reverse_parts(L, ranges):
    """ Reverse the parts of list L indicated by pairs of indices in
        list ranges
    """
    for start, end in ranges:
        L = L[:start] + L[start:end+1][::-1] + L[end+1:]
    return L

print(reverse_parts([1,2,3,4,5], [(0, 2), (3, 4)])) # [3,2,1,5,4]
```

Alternatively, to reverse the list in-place:

```
def reverse_parts(L, ranges):
    for start, end in ranges:
        L[start:end+1] = reversed(L[start:end+1])

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
reverse_parts(my_list, [(0, 2), (3, 4)])
print(my_list)
```